# Close `showModalBottomSheet` after a timeout

Tags: flutter

I tried to close `showModalBottomSheet` widget through an event listener.

```
          showModalBottomSheet(
              useRootNavigator: true,
              context: context,
              builder: (newcontext) {
                return MyBottomDialog();
              });
```

I tried to close this through an event listener:

```
class _MyBottomDialogState extends State<MyBottomDialog> {
...
...
  void initState() {
    _myEventStream.listen((state) {
      if (state == 'timeout') {
        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAncestorStateOfType' of null
.
.
.
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a
reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in
the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: From where are you sending data in the stream?

Comment: It is from a BLoC class. I thought it won't matter where the stream is from. So I removed the codes related to it.

Comment: Let's just say I want to close the dialog after `x` seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I didn't capture properly what the error is saying. 
Even after closing the dialog the stream subscription persists. So the handler is called even if the dialog is not open.

Adding `_streamSubscription.cancel()` in the widget's `dispose` method helps solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The stream class actually comes with a [timeout method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-async/Stream/timeout.html). You just have to feed it a duration and if it exceeds that duration it throws a TimeoutException. Wrap the execution in a try block and call the close modal sheet method from the `on TimeoutException catch (e)` block perhaps.